# How do I get simple editing on a Percent formatted field in WPF TextBox?

Tags: wpf, xaml, ivalueconverter, string-formatting

When you format a TextBox as currency and click to edit it, the $ and commas do not cause a problem, you can just edit and tab with no problem. When you format a field as a percentage things do not work so well.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding CostMarkup, 
                         StringFormat=P}"
                Style="{StaticResource ctrlSpacingTight}" />
```

If the underlying value is 0.1 it correctly displays as 10%, if you go to edit it still shows as 10% the % will cause a problem plus it will change the underlying value from .1 to 10. I wrote a Converter to handle all this but I'm wondering if there isn't a better way. In particular is there a way to handle it the way currency handles it?

There is a built in currency converter so I suspect the currency version of StringFormat uses that. While there is a ZoomPerentageConverter it doesn't do what I would expect. Is there a way to hook in to StringFormat=P and have it invoke my Converter instead of having to go to every  instance and explicitly specify it?

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding CostMarkup, 
                         StringFormat=P,
                         Converter={StaticResource pctConverter}}"
                Style="{StaticResource ctrlSpacingTight}" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've always found that it's easiest to display the raw data when editing, and the formatted value when not.

Here's an example that does that using a trigger

```
<Style x:Key="ctrlSpacingTight" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <!-- Other Style Setters -->
    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding CostMarkup, StringFormat={}{0:C}}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding CostMarkup}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

If `ctrlSpacingTight` is a global style, you can create a style for your TextBox that is `BasedOn` your global style.

```
<Style x:Key="CurrencyTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource ctrlSpacingTight}">
    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding CostMarkup, StringFormat={}{0:C}}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding CostMarkup}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: I'm too new to WPF to fully understand this approach. Where do you put this code? Specifically I'm confused by the TargetType (which I thought meant it applied to all TextBox elements) and the specific Binding of MyValue. Also I thought this syntax went in a resource but "MyValue" isn't going to have meaning there is it? I tried messing around with this but couldn't get it to compile. Could you post a slightly fuller example? This isn't the *simpler* approach I was looking for, but I am interested in knowing how to edit the "raw" value and display the formatted data. Thanks.

Comment: @Tod Sure. I updated the example slightly to use the values you had in your question. The style would get applied to your TextBox, and the default view would display your bound value using a Currency StringFormat. If the TextBox had keyboard focus, it would just display the data without any formatting at all.

Comment: thanks. I feel like an idiot. I was just missing the fact that I should add an x:Key value like I have for **ALL** my other styles and then I can tie this to the control. This is very cool, it allows me to move all the clutter up to UserControl.Resource. I also am now a believer that editing the native format works better for percentages.  I used the second form you posted just changing StringFormat=P since ctrlSpacingTight does reside in a global resource dictionary. Thanks for shining the light on triggers for me.